# regex interval with possible characters before and after number VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to produce a regular expression that can identify a number within an interval in a string in VBA. Sometimes this number has characters around it, other times not (non-consistent notation from a supplier). The expression should identify that 1413 in the three examples below are within the number range 500-2000 (or alternatively that it's *not* in the number range 0-50 or 51-499).

Example:

- `Test 12/2014. Tot.flow:1413 m3` or
- `Test 12/2014. Tot.flow:1413m3` or
- `Test 12/2014. Tot.flow: 1413`

These strings have some identifiers:

- there will always be a colon before the number
- there may be a white space between the colon and the number
- there may be a white space between the number and the `m3`
- `m3` is not necessarily always present, and if not, the number is at the end of the string

So far what I have in my attempt to make an regex that find the number range is `([5-9][0-9][0-9]|[1]\d{3}|2000)`, but this matches all three digit numbers as well (2001 gives a match on 200). However, I understand that I'm missing out on a couple of concepts to achieve the ultimate goal here. I guess my problems are as following:

1. How to start the interval at something not being zero (found lots of questions on intervals starting on zero)
2. How to take into account the variations in notation both for `flow:` and `m3`?

I'm *only* interested in checking that the number lies within the number range. This is driving me bonkers, all help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You could just extract the number with `regExp.Replace()` using `^.*:\s*(\d+).*$` and `$1` replacement, and then use regular integer number comparison to check whether the value is in the expected range.

Comment: @stribizhev Could you please further explain `$1` replacement?

Comment: `$1` is the back-reference to the text captured with the first capturing group (i.e. the `(...)` subpattern).

Comment: Thanks! I love when my problems are simplified :-)

Comment: @stribizhev could you please post your suggestion as an answer so I can upvote and mark as solved :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just extract the number with `regExp.Replace()` using the following regex:

```
^.*:\s*(\d+).*$
```

The replacement part is `$1`.

Then, use usual number comparison to check whether the value is in the expected range (e.g. `If CLng(result) > 499 And If CLng(result) < 2001 Then ...`).

Test macro:

Dim re As RegExp, tgt As String, src  As String

```
Set re = New RegExp
With re
  .pattern = "^.*:\s*(\d+).*$"
  .Global = False
End With
src = "Test 12/2014. Tot.flow: 1413"
tgt = re.Replace(src, "$1")
MsgBox (CLng(tgt) > 499 And CLng(tgt) < 2001)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
:\s?([5-9]\d\d|1\d{3}|2000)\s?(m3|\n)
```

also, your regex `([5-9][0-9][0-9]|[1]\d{3}|2000)` in my opinion is fine, it should not match numbers >500 and 2000<.